# Replacing characters inside the quoted string

Tags: java, apache-pig

As part of my project, I have a CSV file which has comma separated values. But there are few fields which are in quotes. As a result the data is not loaded correctly.
For example: if the data is ==>>   car, deer, "bear, cat"

In the above example, ideally there should be 3 columns. But its being treated as 4 columns due to the presence of a comma between rat and mat. The field "rat,mat" is not clubbed and considered as a single field.

Please suggest if there is something in PIG to handle such scenarios

Comment: you want the final output something like this  col1=car, col2=deer and col3="bear,cat" ?

Comment: yes exactly i need in the above format

Comment: I already posted the solution. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this regex:

have a look here, already ask on SO, very well explained by the user.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [apache CSV library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
**input.csv**

```
car,deer,"bear,cat"
car,deer,"bear,cat"
```

**PigScript: output format1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(\\w+),(\\w+),(.*)$')) AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray,col3:chararray);
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(car,deer,"bear,cat")
(car,deer,"bear,cat")
```

**PigScript Output format2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(\\w+),(\\w+),"(\\w+),(.*)"$')) AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray,col3:chararray,col4:chararray);
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(car,deer,bear,cat)
(car,deer,bear,cat)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String str = "c,b,\"c,d\"";
        System.out.println(str);
           if(str.contains("\"")){
              str= str.replaceAll("\"", " ");
              //System.out.println(str);
              str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
              System.out.println(str);

           }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: this looks like it will not work for any content that contains quotes AND spaces

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have tested above code :)

Comment: Looks like your test coverage is wrong then :). A CSV file with this line `c,a,"c a,b"` should yield 3 distinct elements: `"c", "a", "c a,b". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values