# Regular expressions and delimiters

Tags: regex, delimiter

So I am reading in a file that it divided by commas but some comma's are inside parenthesis. Something like the following.

15000,"111,0000",16000

I am using the delimiter but I don't want the delimiter "," to count the comma that is in the parenthesis. I have looked up similar problems but they say just use a regular expression or regex and it doesn't explain how they work and I don't know how they are suppose to work with a delimiter.

Comment: Use a CSV parser. What is the language you are coding in?

Comment: java sorry I should have included that

Comment: Check https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html

Comment: Or a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes if java is your language.