# Ignoring quoted newlines while splitting CSV data

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

I am trying to split up the data in a csv file to use in my script. I usually split the data by newline then split that line by comma.

like this:

```
 var i;
 var fileData = [];
 var id = 'csv file';
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();
 var newline = dataFile.split('\n');
 for(i in newLine){
  var splitLine = newline[i].split(',');
  fileData.push(splitLine);
};
```

It works well to split up a csv into an array. I am finding out now that it does not work with quoted newlines or commas in cells.

I usually deal with csv data like this 'value1,value2\n value3,value4'. Now I have a csv file that has data like this '"value1\nvalue1",value2\n value3,value4'.

I found a regex way of spliting data. `str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes)

I addapeted it to '\n' like this. `var newline = dataFile.split("\n(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");`

Now it works, but it is very slow. I know nothing about regex, is there a way to edit this regex split to work faster? all I want to do is ignore the newline in double quotes.

**EDIT:**

This does not answer the question, how to make the regex split faster, but I have found a workaround for my particular data.

My data has empty space before a newline, so it will have a comma before it like this ",\n" but the newline that is in quotes have two words between it no commas. "value\nvalue". Do to this I wrote the split like this.

```
var newline = dataFile.split(',\n')
```

Only splitting the lines I want. This works a lot faster than the regex I had, but it would not work for all data, so I don't consider it an answer to my question. It is what I will be using in lieu of a better solution.

Comment: Have you tired to replace/remove the  quotes like so str.replace(/\"/gi, "") , before parsing using split or CSV parser?

Comment: Thanks, but the same thing happens. Both CSV parse and split, split into rows at newline, no matter if in quotes or out.

Answer (score 0):

The utilities function to parse CSV doesn't work for you? [CsvParser Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv-delimiter)

Comment: I could for the regular CSV file, that I am not having problems with. I just tried it on the file I am working on, and it treated the newline in quotes as if it were a newline. Same problem I have with my example.