# Regexp for splitting strings does not work as expected WHEN treating special characters

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I have a regexp to split strings by comma, ignoring commas between single or double quotes, given the following Ruby code:

```
def separate params
  params.split(?!\B('|")[^\"']*),(?![^\"']*('|")\B)
end
```

It DOES work as intended with the exception of strings that feature special characters like `@` or `#`

**Example with expected behavior:**

https://regex101.com/r/xB7rQ7/156

```
"\"search\", placeholder: \"Busca rápida: 1.4 8V, Flex, automático...\", id: \"search_terms\" "
```

**Example with unexpected behavior:**

https://regex101.com/r/xB7rQ7/157

```
"\"search\", placeholder: \"Busca rápida: 1.4 8V, Flex, automático...\", id: \"#search_terms\" "
```

Note that the only difference is the `#` symbol before "search_terms", but the regexp does separate `placeholder` from `id` only in the first case.

Can anyone shed some light into my regexp so that it works in both cases as expected? Please note this is about a specific case of string splitting that is not covered by another questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting on comma outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes)

Comment: Wow, you don't give up do you? You're at revision 157 haha

Comment: Can you post sample strings and their expected outputs?

Comment: Actually, check the links, they have the strings being tested

Comment: @ErvalhouS but you have 157 revisions, can you give us a sample dataset to test against with the expected output?

Comment: Added the examples as asked on edit

Comment: Why don't you match on `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|[^,]+` instead of splitting on `,`?

Comment: Because this matcher doesn't do what I am looking for, it matched only "search"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
,(?=(?:(?:[^"']*["']){2})*[^"']*$)
```

**[Click for Demo](http://rubular.com/r/8bgOFz6Dvu)**

**Explanation:**

- `,` - matches a `,`
- `(?=(?:(?:[^"']*["']){2})*[^"']*$)` - positive lookahead to validate that the `,` match above must be followed by even number of `"` or `'`

  - `(?:(?:[^"']*["']){2})*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither `"` nor `'` followed by either `"` or `'`. The quantifier `{2}` at the end repeats this subsequence 2 times. The quantifier `*` in the end repeats this whole subsequence even number of times(i.e, either 0 or 2 or 4 or 6...occurrences). **This subsequence may have some shortcomings if `"` and `'` appear simultaneously in the string**
  - `[^"']*$` - after finding even number of occurrences there should be no `"` or `'` present before the end of the line