# How split line by comma when comma is included inside in java

Tags: java, java-8

I want to split text that must fit to csv syntax but the text contains comma

Example:
account id  title   text

```
String line = "account123,2222,Thnaks for reaching out,\"Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.\""

String[] splitted = line.split(",");
```

Result:

```
splitted = {String[5]@539} 
 0 = "account123"
 1 = "2222"
 2 = "Thnaks for reaching out"
 3 = ""Hey [[customerFirstName]]"
 4 = " Thanks for reaching out to us.""
```

But I expect

```
splitted = {String[4]@539} 
             0 = "account123"
             1 = "2222"
             2 = "Thnaks for reaching out"
             3 = "Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.\"
```

Comment: Could you not just concat that with a comma?

Comment: Thats mean you need to omit the last comma

Comment: maybe split first with `"` then with `,` help you.

Comment: This question comes up often here, not only in Java, but across basically every language tag.  The usual way to deal with this is to escape each field with a special character, e.g. escape each CSV field with double quotes.

Comment: the Java `.split()` has a second argument which is the "limit".  In your case above you could use ... `.split(",", 3)`

Comment: take a look here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: Consider using CSV parser library, take a look at [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes

Comment: I dont want to use libraries (its a production code ) ..do you have concrete solution , maybe regex ?

Comment: [`String line = "account123,2222,Thnaks for reaching out,\"Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.\"";
String[] split = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

Arrays.stream(split)
        .forEach(System.out::println);`](https://ideone.com/kaCIWn)

Comment: thanks it works :)  split by  - ,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is, as you have found, very brittle. The good news is that there are a number of more robust CSV solutions available. For purposes of this answer, I'll use [openCSV](http://opencsv.sf.net), where your reading code becomes:

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();
reader.close();
csvReader.close();
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String line = "account123,2222,Thnaks for reaching out,\"Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.\",\"Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.\"";
    for (String s : splitByComma(line)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

private static List<String> splitByComma(String line) {
    String[] words = line.split(",");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
        if (words[i].startsWith("\"")) { // collect from the start of the cell;
            String s = words[i].substring(1);
            while (i < words.length - 1) {
                s += "," + words[++i].substring(0, words[i].length() - 1);
                if (words[i++].endsWith("\"")) break; // jump out of the cell after the closing double quotes;
            }
            list.add(s);
            i--;
        } else {
            list.add(words[i]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

And your output will be:

```
account123
2222
Thnaks for reaching out
Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.
Hey [[customerFirstName]], Thanks for reaching out to us.
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a CSV parsing library.

Comment: this regex  split("(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$) ") works for me :)

Comment: @VitalyT don't get me wrong here... but you yourself have used a regex... ;)