# Python regex : issues in skipping delimiter between quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am new to regex and trying to split on the basis of (and/or) as delimiters

I used the solution provided in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893443/5164936

and modified my regex as :

```
re.split(r'(\s+and\s+|\s+or\s+)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', s)
```

which works like a charm for majority of my use cases except for following input:

```
'col1 == "val1" or col2 == \'val1 and " val2\''
```

the split fails for this particular case and I have tried modifying the above regex with different combination with no luck. Can someone please help fix this regex.

Comment: thanks  a ton @WiktorStribiżew this resolves my issue. Will it be possible to break down your regex with some explanation on how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) based solution:

```
import regex

s = 'col1 == "val1" or col2 == \'val1 and " val2\''
res = regex.split(r'''(?V1)(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')\K|(\s+(?:and|or)\s+)''', s)
print([x for x in res if x])
# => ['col1 == "val1"', ' or ', 'col2 == \'val1 and " val2\'']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://rextester.com/ZFMNG66006).

**Details**

- `(?V1)` - flag that allows splitting at zero length matches
- `(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')\K` - a substring in between double or single quotation marks that is discarded from the match value using the `\K` [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) (thus, when this pattern matches, the match is an empty string)
- `|` - or
- `(\s+(?:and|or)\s+)` - 1+ whitespaces, `and` or `or` and again 1+ whitespaces.

Comment: I am stuck again with this regex. This regex doesn't work for the input :  "col2 == 'val1 and val2' ". It splits the string on the "and" word in between the single quotes. Could you please help?

Comment: @HarshBafna The only correct way I see it is with PCRE pattern like `(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|(\s+and\s+|\s+or\s+)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sz5juc/2)). In Python, you may only do something like I posted above. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, highly appreciated. I will try this out. Also, do you mean that it is not possible with the inbuilt re module?

Comment: I am not too good with such complex expressions. Can you suggest some good material from where I can learn regex?

Comment: @HarshBafna I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: You can say I am a beginner. Mostly working in big-data domain and never got a good chance to do hands-on with regex. Thanks for those links. I will go through them whenever I get some time. Till then I will keep disturbing you like this :D

Comment: @HarshBafna I will check if it is possible with `re` and will let you know.

Comment: the above regex returns extra None and blank values in the list for basic split.

Comment: import regex
s = "col1='test'"
regex.split(r'''(?V1)(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')\K|(\s+(?:and|or)\s+)''', s)
["col1='test'", None, '']

Comment: @HarshBafna That is why I have `[x for x in res if x]` in my code in the answer.

Comment: Works for majority of my test cases except for where the data has extra double quotes. for example "col1='McDonal\"s'".

Comment: @HarshBafna No idea what you mean. Are there any escaped quotes in your data?

Comment: yes. it can be like "col1='McDonad\"s'" ,  "col1='McDonald's" , 'col1="McDonand"s', 'col1="McDonald\'s"'.

Comment: the earlier regex you provided based on python re, took care of all these scenarios.

Comment: @HarshBafna I can't see where the issue is since the strings you provided are not quite ready to test against. Can you share a fiddle? Also, try [**this code**](https://rextester.com/OGUXV83761).

Comment: @HarshBafna The `'brand = "McDonald\"s"'`  string literal defines a `brand = "McDonald"s"` literal string. There are 3 unescaped double quotes. There is no way to know where the split should occur in these situations.

Comment: your earlier solution handles this situation :-). re.split(r'(\s+(?:and|or)\s+)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$|(?:[^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)', s)

Comment: @HarshBafna That was still wrong, it did not work correctly. The https://rextester.com/KGHNZ77167 shows me what is not working well. OK, seems like a parser should be much better here. Let me some time to fix it.

Comment: I meant the solution using python re. The only case it didn't handle for me was :  "collegename != 'A and B'"