# Java - read csv file - ignore commas between quote signs

Tags: csv, java-8

I have a csv file with following columns:

```
accountNumber, Name, date
```

the rows can look like this:

```
row 1: 1234, "Name 1", "2018-02-03"
row 2: 3456, "Name 2, with comma", "2016-04-05"
```

I read this csv file with the following lines:

```
private java.util.function.Function<String, ContactContainer> mapToContactContainer = (line) -> {
    final String[] p = line.split(",");
    ...
```

I get a problem with row 2 because there is a comma in the name.
Is there a simple possibility to ignore commas between "..."?

Comment: maybe `line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting on comma outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes)

Comment: why re-invent the wheel when you can use a library - [Apache Commons CSV](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv)