# Splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas between semicolons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

So I have this string:

```
apple;banana;orange, kiwi;onion,strawberry, avocado
```

the above string should split into:

```
   apple
   banana
   orange, kiwi
   onion
   strawberry
   avocado
```

I found a regex function but it only splits the double quotes " "

```
   str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

I tried to replace " " with ; ;

```
   str.split(",(?=(?:[^\;]*\;[^\;]*\;)*[^\;]*$)");
```

but it does't work when I replaced with ;

Comment: are you sure about the wanted result?

Comment: Sounds strange that orange and kiwi aren't splitted. That's a weird split criteria.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes I am sure, something similar asked but with double quotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes

Comment: what is the rule for the last `'onion,strawberry, avocado'` part. why is this part splitted by comma and this `part 'orange, kiwi'` isn't?

Comment: @NinaScholz rule for the last 'onion,strawberry, avocado' is that it should split those with commas

Comment: @NinaScholz the comma between `orange` and `kiwi` is between two semicolons and has to be ignored, as per the title. Commas that don't fit this case should split the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just split by semicolon or by comma, if semicolon is not following.

```js
var string = 'apple;banana;orange, kiwi;onion,strawberry, avocado',
    array = string.split(/;\s*|,\s*(?!.*;)/);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: nice one strange when I add a semicolon at the end of avocado e.g  apple;banana;orange, kiwi;onion,strawberry, avocado; the output is correct but at the end it adds empty string to array, how to ignore the end semicolon? [
        "apple",
        "banana",
        "orange, kiwi",
        "onion",
        "strawberry",
        "avocado",
        ""
      ]

Comment: in this case th splitting works as intended, you could add a filter for removing empty strings, like `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: so following @NinaScholz answer if you looking to ignore semicolon at the end string.split(/;\s*|,\s*(?!.*;)/).filter(Boolean)  thanks for answer NinaScholz

Answer (score 2):

```js
const str = 'apple;banana;orange, kiwi;onion,strawberry, avocado';

console.log(
  str
  
    // split at each semicolon
    .split(';')
    
    // split at each comma, only for the first and last elements
    .map((x,i,arr) => (i==0 || i==arr.length-1) ? x.split(',') : [x])
    
    // merge the arrays
    .reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur], [])

    // trim for clean result
    .map(x => x.trim())
    
)
```

Comment: it's like writing down your expected output.  why I would write a code for that.

Comment: @AZ_ I don't seem to be understanding your comment. Please add further explanations.