# regex - split by comma except when it's inside specific character

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to split string based on `,` except when inside `|` I tried the approach given [Splitting on comma outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes) but doesn't work.

This is where I want to add regex

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(allViolations[c].astype(str).str.split(regex).tolist())
    .rename(lambda x: 'Field{}'.format(x + 1),axis=1)
    for c in allViolations.columns]
```

Here I want to replace regex so can't use `re`. Is there any other way or if I could simplify above statement to use `re`

```
test = 'a,b'
test1 = '|a,b|'

regex = ",(?=(?:[^|]*|[^|]*|)*[^|]*$)"
r = test.split(regex)
print(r) //['a,b']
r1= test1.split(regex)
print(r1) //['|a,b|']
```

Comment: I think it should be re.split `r = re.split(regex, test)` See https://ideone.com/4da1Cp

Comment: The code is like ```astype(str).test.split(regex).tolist() ``` so need to use without re.

Comment: The language is Python?

Comment: yes it's python

Comment: `.astype(str)` are you using pandas ?

Comment: yes I am using pandas

Comment: can you post the first 5 rows of your df or a sample ? with an expected output

Comment: added exactly where I need to use regex

Comment: `r',(?=(?:[^|]*\|[^|]*\|)*[^|]*$)'` [works](https://regex101.com/r/CgGc7r/1), you just forgot to escape the pipes.