# Python parsing update statements using regex

Tags: python, sql, regex, python-2.7, parsing

I'm trying to find a regex expression in python that will be able to handle most of the UPDATE queries that I throw at if from my DB. I can't use sqlparse or any other libraries that may be useful with for this, I can only use python's built-in modules or cx_Oracle, in case it has a method I'm not aware of that could do something like this.

Most update queries look like this:

`UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=2, OTHER_COLUMN=to_date('31-DEC-202023:59:59','DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS'), COLUMN_STRING='Hello, thanks for your help', UPDATED_BY=-100 WHERE CODE=9999;`

Most update queries I use have a version of these types of updates. The output has to be a list including each separate SQL keyword (UPDATE, SET, WHERE), each separate update statement(i.e COLUMN_NAME=2) and the final identifier (CODE=9999).

Ideally, the result would look something like this:

`list = ['UPDATE', 'TABLE_NAME', 'SET', 'COLUMN_NAME=2', 'OTHER_COLUMN=("31-DEC-2020 23:59:59","DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS")', COLUMN_STRING='Hello, thanks for your help', 'UPDATED_BY=-100', 'WHERE', 'CODE=9999']`

Initially I tried doing this using a `string.split()` splitting on the spaces, but when dealing with one of my slightly more complex queries like the one above, the `split` method doesn't deal well with string updates such as the one I'm trying to make in `COLUMN_STRING` or those in `OTHER_COLUMN` due to the blank spaces in those updates.

Comment: `.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")` will do for you as explained here : [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893443/14872512)

Comment: @Younes thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this regex doesn't deal well with the date values or string updates that have a comma in them as it seems to split a string on the commas. Also, I doesn't split the string at the UPDATE, SET, WHERE, keywords. This means that I end up with a ```UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=2``` in the 0 index of my list, where I would like my 0th index to be UPDATE, 1st index to be TABLE_NAME, etc.

Comment: ah i get it, i will post a workaround answer that will get you what you want i hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the shlex module :

```
import shlex
test="UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=2, OTHER_COLUMN=to_date('31-DEC-202023:59:59','DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS'), COLUMN_STRING='Hello, thanks for your help', UPDATED_BY=-100 WHERE CODE=9999;"

t=shlex.split(test)
```

Up to here, we won't get rid of comma delimiters and the last semi one, so maybe we can do this :

```
for i in t:
    if i[-1] in [',',';']:
        i=i[:-1]
```

If we print every element of that list we'll get :

```
UPDATE
TABLE_NAME
SET
COLUMN_NAME=2
OTHER_COLUMN=to_date(31-DEC-202023:59:59,DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS)
COLUMN_STRING=Hello, thanks for your help
UPDATED_BY=-100
WHERE
CODE=9999
```

Not a proper generic answer, but serves the purpose i hope.

Comment: This was brilliant! Solved my issue perfectly. Many thanks!