# Use regex to split a list in a pandas row based on single quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that contains a list of strings. Each string is seperated by a comma.

The list in a row looks something like this:

```
list = ['banana bread is yummy', 'i hate to have some more bread, can't we eat apples?', 'apples are not good for you, they make you hungry']
```

I've been trying to split the list in each row of my column based on regex to get the following output:

```
banana bread is yummy
i hate to have some more bread, can't we eat apples?
apples are not good for you, they make you hungry
```

but when I use

```
s = df.assign(conversation=df['conversation'].str.split(',')).explode('conversation')
```

The whole list get split by commas, regardless of whether they are in the same string or not. Giving me this output:

```
banana bread is yummy
i hate to have some more bread
can't we eat apples?
apples are not good for you 
they make you hungry
```

Any advice on how to use regex for this at all? I tried a couple of things but just get very random results.

EDIT:

Another method I tried was this:

```
df['conversation'] = df['conversation'].str.strip('[]')
```

I first removed the square brackets from each row and then split everything. Whilst this method works, it leaves me with random empty rows.

Comment: check the index ~ if index same they are the same string before ~

Comment: @BENY sorry, I don't quite get that. Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to answer my own question based on this response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes) :-)

```
s = df.assign(conversation =df['conversation'].str.split(",(?=(?:[^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)")).explode('conversation')
```