# CSV Coma Delimiter Split in Spark RDD but NOT to split coma with in double quotes

Tags: csv, rdd, double-quotes, scala-spark

I have a CSV file with data as below

id,name,comp_name

1,raj,"rajeswari,motors"

2,shiva,amber kings

my requirement is to read this file to spark RDD, then do map split with coma delimiter.
but giving code this splits all comas
val splitdata = data.map(_.split(",")

i do not want to split coma with in double quotes.
But i DO NOT want to use REGEX expression. is there any simple efficient method to acheive this?

Also 2nd requirement is read above csv file to Spark Dataframe and show it but i need to see double quotes in result
output should look like

id                name            comp_name

1                 raj             "rajeswari,motors"

2                 shiva          amber kings

double quotes are not shown normally but is any way to do it?

I am using spark 2.4 / scala 2.11 / Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try using dataframe instead of RDD?

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("csv/file/path")
```

There won't be direct way, you have to use regex like this below to ignore "," enclosed between ""

```
val raw = sc.textFile("file:///tmp/stackoverflow_q_72457003.csv")
raw.map(_.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")(2)).foreach(println)
```

You'd get output like this

"rajeswari,motors"

amber kings

Refer this post for understanding expression : [Splitting on comma outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes)

[image]

Comment: That was my 2nd requirement. but i need to show double quotes in data. data frame do NOT show double quotes. out put i receive do not have double quotes if i read with DF

1 raj  rajeswari,motors

2 shiva amber kings

Comment: I think using expression would be the best approach. because while splitting we need to see if a comma is enclosed by quotes. only regex has that capability and no other way for this.

Comment: ok thanks. i thought there may be any other solution or any direct methods as i am new to this tech i am not much familiar.